# Autofill formula wont adjust properly because it is a merged cell with a reference to a single cell as part of the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This formula: `=Manpower!E53/@'Daily Install'!B131` is found in cell 'Daily Install" at B133.

- E53 is a calculated cell on page 'Manpower"
- B131 is a calculated cell on page 'Daily Install'

This formula works fine, however, this is a weekly summation of the manpower/footage of pipe installed per week over months.

When I try to Autofill drag the formula, the E53 portion changes by 7 each time, (should be sequential E53, F53, G53 etc.) I think because of the B131 reference being a merged cell of 7 cells.  I need to copy this formula weekly over a 2 year period, therefore across to approximately cell ABC133, but that would mean going in and changing each cell value.  Is there another way that this can be achieved rather than manual input of changing each cell value?